# Custom RoutedEvent as EventTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, eventtrigger, routedevents

I have my own shape class

```
public sealed class MirrorTile : Shape
```

and in this class I added the event

```
public static readonly RoutedEvent SelectedEnterEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("SelectedEnter", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MirrorTile));

public event RoutedEventHandler SelectedEnter
{
    add
    {
        this.AddHandler(SelectedEnterEvent, value);
    }

    remove
    {
        this.RemoveHandler(SelectedEnterEvent, value);
    }
}
```

and want to use it in this way

```
<shapes:MirrorTile>
    <shapes:MirrorTile.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SelectedEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SelectShape}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </shapes:MirrorTile.Triggers>
</shapes:MirrorTile>
```

After starup I get the exception:
`{"RoutedEventConverter cannot convert from System.String."}`

What I'm doing wrong and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="shapes:MirrorTile.SelectedLeave">`

the namespace was missing also.

Comment: @McGarnagle: Are you sure about the second colon? My VS stops telling me there is an error when I replace it with a point.

Comment: `namespace:ClassName.EventName`

Answer (score 7):

You have to provide the type as well:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MirrorTile.SelectedEnter"></EventTrigger>
```

Edit upon comment:

Have you tried adding a namespace to your XAML declaration?

```
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
```

Then fix this to:

```
 <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:MirrorTile.SelectedEnter"></EventTrigger>
```

Comment: I tried this but I get an exception also `{"Type reference cannot find type named '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation}MirrorTile'."}`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the type that defines your event:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MirrorTile.SelectedEnter">
```

Comment: I tried this but I get an exception also  `{"Type reference cannot find type named '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation}MirrorTile'."}`