# How to handle a custom RoutedEvent fired from a UserControl from inside the ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm

Currently I have a usercontrol that fires a registered RoutedEvent like this:

```
    protected virtual void OnScrollEvent(object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        AssociatedObject.RaiseEvent(new DateTimeEventArgs(OnVisualChartRangeChangedEvent, minDate, maxDate));
    }
```

The mainwindow container currently handles this event by calling a method from the view like this.

```
<Grid>
    <historicChart:HistoricChartControl behaviours:ChartBehavior.OnVisualChartRangeChanged="RoutedEventHandler"/>
</Grid>
```

and the code behind...

```
    private void RoutedEventHandler(object sender, DateTimeEventArgs dateTimeEventArgs)
    {
               //do stuff here...
    }
```

But what I would like is for this to conform to the MVVM model, so that my handler should be implemented  the viewmodel and not in the view.

How can I do this? Could someone post me a brief example of how I could go about this?

Thanks in advnce

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CallMethodAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195660.aspx) to invoke your ViewModel handler.

See this on how to create an EventTrigger for your custom RoutedEvent :
[Custom RoutedEvent as EventTrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068471/custom-routedevent-as-eventtrigger)

Comment: This only works for the when built-in events such as MouseEnter are fired. I want to call a method in the viewmodel when a custom routed event is fired from the usercontrol.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want to call a method, not implement a storyboard...